# React - Update custom hook's ref in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have implemented the following custom hook:

```
export default function useCamera() {
   const [cameraRatio, setCameraRatio] = useState(Camera.Constants.DesiredRatio);
   const [cameraType, setCameraType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
   const [flashMode, setFlashMode] = useState(
      Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off
   );

   const camRef = useRef(null); <----- Interesting part
   const cameraTypeRef = useRef(cameraType);
   const isTakingPhoto = useRef(false);

   const takePhoto = () => {
      if(!camRef.current) return; <----- Interesting part

      ...
   }

   const flip = () => {}

   const toggleFlash = () => {}

   ...

   return {
      camRef,
      cameraRatio,
      cameraType,
      flashMode,
      takePhoto,
      flip,
      toggleFlashMode,
      ...
   }
}
```

So, in my Camera component, I just do:

```
function Camera({ ... }) {
   const {
      camRef, <---- Interesting part
      takePhoto,
      ...
   } = useCamera();
  
   return <NativeCamera ref={camRef} onTakePhoto={takePhoto} ... />
}
```

As you can see, I am passing the camRef to "NativeCamera". This ref is defined in my custom hook "useCamera", and received in my "Camera" component, which just pass the ref to the child.

But this doesn't work. Any workaround?

Comment: Whats the exact issue you're facing?

Comment: Please , can you share all your code in sandbox - codesandbox.io/s/react-native-q4qymyp2l6?from-embed=&file=/… or snack.expo.dev , it will be much easier to me help you with all code . Try to set ref like this : <TextInput ref={(ref) => { setRef(ref); }} />

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact issue you're facing but in your particular case, it would be better to pass the ref as an argument to the hook for usage i.e. useCamera(camRef.current) and not get it from the custom hook. That would make the nesting simpler, currently it seems weird for the custom hook to be the starting point for the ref. Instead it should be initialized in the Camera component

Comment: Is the `NativeCamera` component a class or functional component?

Comment: Functional. BTW, I think that passing the ref as argument is a good option. Thx very much.